# I am getting error in my code with try exception

Tags: python

```
try:
    for v in d.values():
        for item in v[1:]:
            if item != v[0]:
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('this is inconsistent')
```

I am getting the following output-

```
except ValueError:
```

^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 5):

If this is your entire code snippet, then after the line `if item != v[0]:`, there isn't a statement.  You would need to put one there.

If you would like to *raise* an exception instead, then you don't need the `try...except` block around that piece of code.  You would frame it as such:

```
for v in d.values():
    for item in v[1:]:
        if item != v[0]:
            raise ValueError('this is inconsistent')
```

Comment: what if I just need to check the condition and if the condition satisfies it will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

The error may be because the program is expecting a statement after if item != v[0]:, but it finds none and is treating the except ValueError: line as the next line which is not at its right Indent.